# How to enable Hardware acceleration in Ubuntu 16.04LTS with AMD?

Tags: drivers, 16.04, fglrx, amd-graphics, hardware-acceleration

I've a system with AMD GX-412HC SOC with Radeon(TM) R3E Graphics ×4

I've read that proprietary drivers (fglrx) aren't supported but I still need to enable hardware acceleration for my video player (mpv)

```
mpv --hwdec=vaapi -vo opengl-hq video.mp4
```

This is what I get

```
Playing: video.mp4
 (+) Video --vid=1 (*) (h264)
 (+) Audio --aid=1 --alang=eng (*) (aac)
libva info: VA-API version 0.39.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/radeonsi_drv_video.so
libva info: va_openDriver() returns -1
libva info: VA-API version 0.39.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/radeonsi_drv_video.so
libva info: va_openDriver() returns -1
VO does not support requested hardware decoder, or loading it failed.
AO: [pulse] 48000Hz 5.1 6ch float
Using software decoding.
VO: [opengl-hq] 1920x804 yuv420p
AV: 00:00:01 / 00:02:28 (0%) A-V:  0.000 Dropped: 8

Exiting... (Quit)
```

Calling "Top" I see that processor use is 100%.

What can I do?

Comment: [This link](https://github.com/mpv-player/mpv/issues/1600) has the same problem, may be useful for you.

Comment: 1. What is the codec of the video? 2. Find out if it is supported with vainfo for HW-acceleration.